# Insert a 'Return' after the 60th char in every line for a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I am having some trouble with my custom RichTextBox control.

The RichTextBox does not seem to have any concept of a "Lines" collection.  But I need to manage the text by line.

Is there a way to get AND update a line of text in a RichTextBox?

**The exact scenario I am going for is to look at each line in the RichTextBox and, if the line has more than 60 chars, insert a `Environment.NewLine` after the 60th char.**

Update:
I have found that you can GET a line with this code:

```
richTextBox.Document.ContentStart.GetLineStartPosition(lineNumber);
```

**But I still have no way to UPDATE a line.**

Comment: Not an answer per se, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.100).aspx) I see a property called Lines

Comment: What if the 60th char is in the middle of a word?

Comment: @Steve, that example is the windows forms RichTextBox. The WPF implementation may be different. This is RichTextBox for WPF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx

Comment: @Steve - WPF does not have the "Lines" property.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - Ideally I will go back to the previous word break.  But for now, I will be very very happy with just inserting in the middle of the word.  (Or anything that even kind of works.)

Comment: So TextWrapping does not do what you need?  Are you binding to a FlowDocument?

Comment: @Blam - TextWrapping is based off of pixels.  I need something based off of chars.  (Normally I would use a fixed font, but I am wanting to be able to bold some of my text (hence the Rich in RichTextbox), so that messes up the fixed font idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple need to iterate over the lines, check the length, if it's longer than 60, add a new line character.  Repeat for all the characters in the line, and return the result.

Below is an outline of the code

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextPointer line = richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(0);
    if (line.GetOffsetToPosition(richTextBox1.CaretPosition) > 60)
    {
        line.GetPositionAtOffset(60, LogicalDirection.Forward).InsertLineBreak();
    }
}
```

The above code is useful, if you are running the formatting once.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up, but in WPF RichTextBox does not have a "Lines" property.

Comment: @Vaccano Revised my answer to account for WPF.  Essentially, get the lines, split on line breaks to get lines, and work from there.

Comment: Kami, thank you for the answer.  This code works, but it had significant performance issues.  Normal typing is very laggy on my beefed up dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

This code adds a new line if the current line is too long.  (This only works on the current line, so it would need to be adapted to more lines for pasting.)

```
    private const int lineLimit = 60;
    private static void BlockCurrentToNotExceedMaxChars(TextPointer currentLocation)
    {
        var currentStart = currentLocation.GetLineStartPosition(0);
        var nextStart = currentLocation.GetLineStartPosition(1);
        var currentEnd = (nextStart != null ? nextStart : currentLocation.DocumentEnd).GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);

        TextRange currentLine = new TextRange(currentStart, currentEnd);
        if (currentLine.Text.Trim().Length > lineLimit)
        {
            currentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(lineLimit + 1).InsertLineBreak();
        }
    }
```